# self.view.background color is overridding uinavigationbar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set background color for the entire view and the navigation bar background color

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But the navigation bar color is not appearing in red color. Why is it so? Anyhelp could be appreciated.
[image]

I want navigation bar background to be in red apart from that all views should be in ash color including status bar.

Comment: Please post screenshots of your storyboard and the screenshots of your output from the simulator

Comment: where you added the code in viewdidload or else

Comment: Am adding it in viewDidLoad

Comment: u want to apply same color throughout your application or it is for particular view?

Comment: @Sivagami - add in viewdidappear and try once

Comment: not working @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Sivagami -c an you add some screen shot or else some additional code

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a `isTranslucent` flag to false?

```
self.navigationBar?.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationController.navigationBar?.barTintColor = SOMECOLOR
self.navigationController.navigationBar?.isTranslucent = false
self.view.backgroundColor = SOMECOLOR
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Click on **Navigation Controller**

2.Now Open **Show Document Outline** that's gives in your story board's left side.

3.Click on **Navigation Bar**.

[You can show image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnSFV.png)

4.Now go on **Attributes Inspector** and now you can directly set navigation bar color from **Bar Tint**. You can change **Title** Font and **Title Color** ,also.

[You can show image  here 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxYnN.png)